# Android dashcam app that records video with Map overlay

Tags: android, maps, video-recording

Is there an Android dashcam app that records videos with a tiny map at the bottom corner?

Like how games (like GTA) do it:

[image]

Main Requirements:

- It should record the video
- It should add a tiny map, possibly in a tilted way, showing my current location

Maps used could be any but prefer google maps.

Minor requirements (optional)

- Should be able to upload to cloud (Google Drive, or Youtube account)
- Should work like a typical dashcam/security camera. Especially with the ability to discard previous video data after a pre-defined limit (like 1-24 hr)
- Should be able record from both cameras (front and back)

---

- OS: Android
- License: Any